# About website domains

Tags: domains, web-hosting

If I have `example.com/foo`, I have a directory of `example`. But in some cases (as this website too), the address starts with something else, for example `blog.example.com`.

What is the `blog.` thing named? Is that a subdomain? How do I look up for that in my host service to see if I can get these in my own website?

Comment: Yes. It is a sub-domain.domain.tld. Most web hosts will allow sub-domains, however, sub-domains should only be used with proper consideration. It is not an arbitrary consideration nor is it necessarily a complex one. You would have to have your own domain registered and a web host that allows sub-domains. From there, we can help you with the consideration, set-up, and use.

Answer (score 1):

It's called a subdomain, indeed. Whether you can use them is completely up to your host; they might be included in your hosting plan. You should contact them to find out.